# How to make FirefoxDriver use existing profile?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to tell the `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver` of `Selenium` to use an existing profile along with its cookies and proxy settings, so I'm doing:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\u72231ej.other"));

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

But it seems that a new profile is created no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffprofile.setPreference(); //Set your preference here
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

You can get the list of preferences by typing about:config in the firefox address bar.
New driver will have a profile with your settings applied.