# Selenium WebDriver works but SLOW (Java)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, screenshot, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to take a screenshot of webpages. It runs great. However, from the time I hit run in eclipse to the time the screenshot shows up in my local drive is 7-10 seconds. Most of the latency seems to be launching Firefox.

Code:

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.cnn.com");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\test\\screenshot.png"));
```

How can I speed up this process? Is there a way that I can use an already opened Firefox browser to save on opening a new one? Is this code somehow heavy?

Details: Tried on CentOS box and Win7 box both using eclipse. myspeedtest.net shows 22Mbps down and 1 Mbps up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are asking for (allowing `WebDriver` to attach to a running browser) has been an issue now for [almost 3 years](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18). To date, this feature has still not been added. As far as I am aware, there is no way to make Firefox load any faster. You can try a few other tricks though.

```
fp.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable")
```

Quoting the caveat from [this page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver):

> There is beta feature to make firefox not wait for the full page to
>   load after calling .get or .click. This may cause immediate find's to
>   break, so please be sure to use an implicit or explicit wait too. This
>   is only available for Firefox and not other browsers.

You can also try [loading with a profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771592/how-to-make-firefoxdriver-use-existing-profile) and see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 5):

From the things I learned elsewhere -

1. Turn off automatic updates for your browser/plugins
2. Set your IIS (or equivalent) app timeouts to zero
3. Create a base Selenium Fixture for use in your tests
4. Update to the latest version of Selenium
5. Warm up your apps prior to testing
6. Short tests
7. Pre-populate cookies.

References:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/selenium-reuse-existing-browser-session-instead-of-opening-new-windows

http://www.codeweavers.net/6-ways-to-speed-up-selenium-tests/

http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/02/speed-up-your-selenium-tests/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm the author of the six ways article - glad you found it useful. Just to echo what's here, the key is keep your apps warm, don't let your servers timeout and make sure nothing will try to update during a test run.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/a2fNfF-mD_E) shows a possible explanation.

To summarize, Selenium loops through all network cards and calls a method (getHostName) that takes a long time for virtual network cards. Disabling them solved the problem of the OP in the thread.

(In my own case, I am unable to disable any of them and have to wait at the start of each test case...)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Windows and the cause was related to resolving `localhost`. In this case there are two ways to fix it:

- replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 (so go to urls like `http://127.0.0.1`). However this messes with `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` setting when testing against web application using NTLM authentication, as it requires a hostname, not an IP address
- change `hosts` (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) to directly solve localhost to 127.0.0.1:

  ```
  # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  #   ::1             localhost
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question has already been answered, but I hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

If all you need to do is take screenshots. I recommend using Awesomium.NET.
http://awesomium.com/

Doing this in C# rather than Java shouldn't be a major difficulty since they have similar syntax. It also supports C++ if you want to run your application on Linux. I presume it will be significantly faster than the WebDriver.

Use this if you choose C++: http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c/

For C#.NET: http://awesomium.com/docs/1_7_rc3/sharp_api/

Comment: Marv how long does it take you in general to click compile and get your generated screenshot?

Comment: this has a dead link

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with 64bit version of IEDriverServer,
I added the property requireWindowFocus with Value:"true".

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```