# Selenium WebDriver extremely slow on Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium WebDriver 2.31.0 with Java, both on 64-bit linux and 64-bit windows. Our pages load pretty quickly, about 2 seconds. However, running WebDriver tests pages can load for 30seconds or so. Is there some generic situation when WebDriver runs very slow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020841/selenium-webdriver-works-but-slow-java

Comment: Have you set an implicit wait time on the driver object?  This can really slow things down.  Can you show us some code, it's hard to diagnose an issue with absolutely no information.

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Comment: I found this answer usefull :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020841/selenium-webdriver-works-but-slow-java 

I hope it helps you too !

Comment: Things were working perfectly fine until I upgraded to Webdriver 2.33 with FF 22.0. Tests are extremely slow now. I did downgrade to the previous versions i.e Webdriver 2.26 with FF 19.02 with no change in result. Not sure what has gone wrong

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same situation.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with loading the pages and sometimes getting a timeout error. I was using the WebDriver with Java and JUnit. Then I updated to the last versions of the libraries for Java and it worked well.

Comment: the strange thing is that even waiting for http response takes long. So if I log into our page manually, it takes like 1 second. If a Selenium test logs in, it takes about 30seconds. It doesn't make sense as it is waiting for page response. I would understand if the problem is that Selenium is slow in finding elements...