# Selenium webdriver script is taking more time to execute around 5-7 min when it tries to input text in textbox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox-driver

i have one screen in which we are able to select 2 option

1. Online Delivery
2. offline delivery and they are label

As soon as we select any 1 option then selenium script becomes too slow

Next option is to enter input text in phone number which takes around 5-7 min

```
    if(deliveryoption.equals("UK_Delivery"))
        {
            /*WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='deliveryChoices']/div/label[@for='selectHomeDelivery']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);*/
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".deliveryChoiceSelect>label[for='selectHomeDelivery']>div[class='eMarketingSpot']")).click();
            //Thread.sleep(3000);
            //WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id("changeTitleAndNameDetailsLink"));
            //CommonUtils.verifyAndClick(link,"", true);    
            //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", phoneNumber);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div[2][@class='singleInput']/input[@id='_phone1']")).sendKeys("1234567890" + Keys.TAB);
            //CommonUtils.verifyElementExist(phoneNumber, "Phone number text box not present", true);
            //  CommonUtils.verifyAndInputText(phoneNumber, "1234567890", "Phone number text box not present", true);
            CommonUtils.verifyAndInputText(PostalCode, "W1A 1AB", "Postal code number text not present", true);
            CommonUtils.verifyAndClick(FindAddressBtn, "Find address button not available", true);
            CommonUtils.waitMaxSeconds();
            CommonUtils.verifyAndClick(ChooseDeliveryOption, "Select Delivery button not available", true);
```

Comment: are you using IE here?

Comment: No Firefox browser i am using

Comment: Okay, actually similar question is asked and answered in here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020841/selenium-webdriver-works-but-slow-java