# Java Selenium WebDriver with Yandex

Tags: java, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver, yandex

At the moment, I use Firefox as browser for my Java Application with Selenium. But Firefox is slow.

Is it possible to use Yandex as browser? Didn't find anything in Google. Does Selenium supports Yandex? For Chrome I need the .exe for using Chrome as browser. Is this possible with Yandex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I recall, *there is no WebDriver for the Yandex ("Яндекс") browser*. In other words, there is no way to automate this browser through selenium.

---

Also, there are some performance tips and further links here:

- [Selenium WebDriver works but SLOW (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020841/selenium-webdriver-works-but-slow-java)

Answer (score 1):

Yandex browser can work with Selenium WebDriver using Operadriver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\testselenium\\drivers\\operadriver.exe");
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\Application\\browser.exe");
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(options);
driver.get("https://docs.seleniumhq.org");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for ( 4 years later :) ):

https://github.com/yandex/YandexDriver