# Selenium WebDriver manager().getCookies() returns 0 always

Tags: java, cookies, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium WebDriver 
 `manager().getCookies()` in `InternetExplorerDriver` **always** returns 0 elements!
P.S. version 2.32.0.0

Comment: Can you give some code examples?

Comment: Are you sure visbile cookies exist?  What is displayed if you run "document.cookie" in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I dig deeply and find out that its problem in IE10, it doesn't show cookies at all ( I try in console by command 'document.cookie').

Answer (score 15):

If the cookies are [HTTPOnly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) you can't read them from Javascript/Selenium

Comment: You can see this in the Chrome Cookies spec:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies

Comment: At the moment you can read httponly with selenium. But, of cause, you cannot do that with Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't understand why `driver.manage().getCookies();` always returns with size 0 in FF and IE.

but I found this workaround, using `executeScript`

```
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();

if (cookies.size() == 0) { // To support FF and IE
    String cookiesString = (String) driver.executeScript("return document.cookie");
    cookies = parseBrowserCookies(cookiesString);
}




private Set<Cookie> parseBrowserCookies(String cookiesString) {
    Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<>();

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(cookiesString)) {
        return cookies;
    }

    Arrays.asList(cookiesString.split("; ")).forEach(cookie -> {
        String[] splitCookie = cookie.split("=", 2);
        cookies.add(new Cookie(splitCookie[0], splitCookie[1], "/"));
    });

    return cookies;
}
```

Comment: //Replace driver.executeScript with js.executeScript like:
JavascriptExecutor js;
js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String cookiesString = (String) js.executeScript("return document.cookie");

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your webdriver is on the domain you are expecting the cookie to be set on?
`getCookies` only returns the cookies for the current domain.

Answer (score 3):

```
Set<Cookie> allcookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
System.out.println(allcookies);
```

Comment: While the code you've provided may answer the question - adding some content to explain why will ensure this is actually a helpful answer. Please review [ask] if you're unsure of how to write an answer.

Comment: The question is not how to get cookies with Selenium, is why `driver.manage().getCookies()` not working in IE. So this is not answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be with the 64-bits driver. I have tried with the 32-bits driver and it works. If using WebDriverManager just do:

```
WebDriverManager.iedriver().arch32().setup();
```

Another thing that could be related(not very sure) is a setup for Internet Explorer 11 at registry level, see [Selenium IE driver information](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration):

> For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target
>   computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
>   of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the
>   key you must examine in the registry editor is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
>   installations, the key is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
>   FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
>   created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
>   DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set cookie first, AFAIK webdriver always start with fresh session.
Instead you can try to setup user profile like this:
[How to make FirefoxDriver use existing profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771592/how-to-make-firefoxdriver-use-existing-profile)

Comment: I'm using IE, and my session cookie are sent with next requests, but I can't get them from webdriver. I think its problem with IE
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970490/ie10-console-cant-see-cookies-by-command-document-cookie

Answer (score -3):

This is what you could do to get all cookies

```
allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

Comment: I know that.  The problem is in IE or in driver, I can't get cookies at all! Cookies exists, but driver returns 0...