# IE10 console can't see cookies by command document.cookie

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, session-cookies, internet-explorer-10

IE10 console can't see cookies by command `document.cookie`, but send them in the request!

Update:
[image]

Comment: Are the cookies not HTTP Only cookies? If they are then you can't access them in JavaScript

Comment: No, they are not HTTP Only )

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I am using 10.0.9200.16519 and it appears to work for me as expected.

[image]

Comment: Try clean cookie, login and on the second page look for session cookie (for example). In my case I can surfe few pages without session cookie and document.cookie result '', BUT cookies are sent with request.